# generate SCRAM-SHA-1 hash of a password

Tags: openssl, cryptography

I am looking for a simple way (perhaps using openssl) to generate SCRAM-SHA-1 hash of a password for use for Prosody Jabber Server. The passwords on the server are stored in the following form:

```
["iteration_count"] = 4096;
["stored_key"] = "f76e63cb5bb7f78e99b07196646c39a0f9422ef7";
["salt"] = "5317fe92-be09-4e0c-8501-55e5fb325543";
["server_key"] = "eb701c012450813185104934f88a9d07a7f211d9";
```

Can anybody suggest something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, cryptography isn't my strong suite 8-) but this library looks to give you what you want. It's in Python:

http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.scram.html

You can use it like so:

```
>>> hash = scram.encrypt("password", rounds=1000, algs="sha-1,sha-256,md5")
>>> hash
'$scram$1000$RsgZo7T2/l8rBUBI$md5=iKsH555d3ctn795Za4S7bQ,sha-1=dRcE2AUjALLF
tX5DstdLCXZ9Afw,sha-256=WYE/LF7OntriUUdFXIrYE19OY2yL0N5qsQmdPNFn7JE'
```

#### References

- [Modular Crypt Format](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html#modular-crypt-format)
- [GNU SASL Library - Libgsasl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/)